# A bool function doesn't work in stable_sort function

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

The shipwreck;

Input a number, than a vector of type Passenger passengers(number), where Passenger is a struct that consists of string name and string status; 
the problem is to sort the passengers who was on the ship by the next priority:
   a) first who leaves the ship is rat, than the ship leaves whoman or a child, than the ship leaves a man, the last one who leaves the ship is the captain;
   b) it is necessary to write a bool function which we will use in function stable_sort to sort the vector of passengers;

I tried this:

```
  int Priority1(Passenger pas)
{ 
    if(pas.status == "rat")
        return 3;
    if(pas.status == "woman" || pas.status == "child")
        return 2;
    if(pas.status == "man")
        return 1;
    if(pas.status == "captain")
        return 0;
}
bool Priority(Passenger pas1, Passenger pas2)
{
    return Priority1(pas1) > Priority1(pas2);
}
```

Comment: Your function always returns true?

Comment: @ypnos No, sometimes it falls off the end, resulting in undefined behavior (but in practice, returning an unspecified value.

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to implement an ordering function for one of the
standard library functions, your function is trivially wrong,
because it returns true if both passengers are rats.  To
establish a proper ordering function, comparing any two entries
in the same equivalence class must return false.

Further down... what happens if both passengers are men?  None
of your `if` are true, and you fall off the end, resulting in
undefined behavior.  (FWIW: it's generally a bad practice to
throw `return` around right and left in the function.  One
single return, as the last line in the function, and outside of
any control structure is a good general rule.)

Anyway, the approach I would take would be to to map both values
to an integral priority, and then return `Priority(pas1) < Priority(pas2);`.  Much simpler, and guaranteed not to miss
any cases.

Comment: How can i add status in bool function which gives the highest priority to rat than to woman or a child than to man?

Comment: Just as I said: map the different passenger types to an integral value representing the priority, and the compare the integral values.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(pas1.status == "man" && pas2.status != "woman" && pas2.status == "child" && pas2.status != "rat")
```

I think the third condition `pas2.status == "child"`, should be `pas2.status != "child"`

Also, there is no default `return` statement in the function.